# Error al usar el comando pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

Buenas a todos, haciendo una prueba de concepto en casa me encontré con que al usar el comando "pip3 install -r requeriments.txt" me salta el siguiente error:

> ```
> No command 'pip3' found, did you mean:
> Command 'pip' from package 'python-pip' (universe)
> pip3: command not found
> ```

Al parecer es un error relacionado con python y entonces instalé todo lo necesario que me sugerían para usar el comando pip pero aun así me sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Estoy sobre una maquina virtual con ubuntu 12.04 (x64). Alguien sabría explicar el fallo?

Comment: Has probado `yum install pip3` ? es posible que no tengas las utilidades instaladas. De todas maneras el error parece que te sugiere que uses pip en lugar de pip3, puedes probar también

Comment: No tienes pip instalado para Python 3. Para instalar pip3 en Ubuntu si no recuerdo mal es `sudo apt-get  install python3-pip` (en la terminal por supuesto).

Answer (score 1):

Pip es un comando para instalar paquetes de python, dependiendo de como lo instales necesitas usar 'pip' 'pip2' o 'pip3'

Normalmente  pip3 instala paquetes en python3 dist-packages, 
pip2 instala paquetes en python2 dist-packages, 
y pip en el primero que se instalo (podrias tener varias versiones de python2 y python3)

Se puede usar pip usando:

```
python3 -m pip install package
```

Para ver si alguno de los pythons que tienes te esta dando problemas puedes usae el comando:

```
ls /usr/local/lib | grep python
```

Que te dirá que versiones de python tienes instaladas